# Commas in a Python math argument

Tags: python

I noticed by accident that Python's primitive math operators support commas in both numeric arguments. A tuple is returned. What is it doing and why is this syntax supported?

Here are a few examples:

```
>>> 2,10,2 / 2
(2, 10, 1)

>>> 2,10,2 * 2
(2, 10, 4)

>>> 2,10,2 % 2,3
(2, 10, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Is this an order of operations question?

Comment: I think this is equivalent to `(2, 10, (2/2))`, `(2, 10, (2*2))`, and `(2, 10, (2%2), 3)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `2,10,2 / 2`, the operation performed actually is:

```
2, 10, (2 / 2)
```

Hence you get the `(2, 10, 1)` as output.

In Python, tuples are actually a collection of values separated by commas, the surrounding parentheses are to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using a tuple (which is why the output is surrounded by the parenthesis.) The math is only happening on one element of the tuple.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 0):

This is especially visible in interactive mode.  Python semantics turn a comma-separated sequence into a tuple.  This underlies the "tuple unpacking" you know from function returns, such as

```
value, status = my_func(args)
```

If you write

a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

You get the corresponding assignments just as if you'd put `(1, 2, 3)` on the RHS.  Similarly,

```
a = 1, 2, 3
```

Gets you an `a` value of the entire tuple, `(1, 2, 3)`.

Note that you need an all-or-none approach: one variable on the LHS, or exactly the correct quantity for the tuple length.

Answer (score 0):

You are just defining a tuple, it's not that math operators supports commas. What python is doing there, is assuming you are doing a tuple (because of the commas), so it evaluate each value between the comas, and then store it to the tuple. Not a thing about primitive math operator, it's just how python interprets commas.
You could do `1,"a","a"+"b",2+5`, and that would give you the tuple `(1, "a", "ab", 7)`.

An easy and simplist way of giving an answer is: If python finds a comma in your code, it assumes you put it there for separating data. Then, if he finds `1, 1+1`, you are giving two data, a number one, and an expresion 1+1. Python evaluates the expresion and says "Oh, its 2". Then, he returns you the `(1,2)` tuple.

Im not an expert at python compiler, so don't rely 100% on my answer, but I'm quite sure that's the reason.